# Haskell & Snap: Transient per request state

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

How do I set per request transient-state in Snap?

Looking at http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snaplets-tutorial it says

> Handler b v has a MonadState v instance. This means that you can access all your snaplet state through the get, put, gets, and modify functions that are probably familiar from the state monad.

So I am trying the following:

```
data App = App
    { _test :: Int
    }
```

And then in the handler:

```
someHandler :: Handler App App ()
someHandler = do
    test <- gets _test
    liftIO $ print test
    put ( 2 :: Int _test
```

However I get the error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘Handler App App a0’
  Expected type: (App -> Int) -> Handler App App a0
    Actual type: (App -> Int) -> ()
• The function ‘put’ is applied to two arguments,
  its type is ‘s0 -> m0 ()’,
  it is specialized to ‘Int -> (App -> Int) -> ()’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: put (2 :: Int) _test
  In the expression:
    do { test <- gets _test;
         liftIO $ print test;
         put (2 :: Int) _test;
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: `put` takes one argument, but you give it two (the error clearly states this -  "The function ‘put’ is applied to two arguments" - did you read it?). You probably want `put (App { _test = 2 })`, or use lenses.

Comment: wow. it was that simple. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes, I read the warning, but didn't even pay attention to it. I was focusing on the first part. I promise, I am not that stupid as it appears :D